# How can I create a group with my project on GitHub and the FrontEnd and BackEnd associated to be repos of this group(project)?

Tags: git, github

I'm building a web-app and I want to make a group with the name of the app to contain the two major part of a web site, the Frontend and Backend. How can I do this? Or maybe some suggestions !

I have read other question on this topic but neither explained in detail. Maybe we can find a more complete answer to help people that aren't familiar with GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Its not that much of a problem, you can do it in two ways. Either use:

1.GitHub (User Interface).
or

2.git bash (Command Line) (Preferred)

Firstly create a new repository and name it without spaces (use _ for a better naming)
Then You will have to add folders and files to it using GitHub.
[link](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-new-repository)

Or you can make this empty repos and dont add any readme, gitignore or license, just create and follow these instructions:

[GIT CLI TO ADD PROJECT FOLDERS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9tjC.png)

then, invite your group memebers as contributors to the project by clicking on settings in your repo, then click manage access. and invite contributors. this will send them an email to accept the invitation.